# Build a Nuget Docker Image in Debian

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nuget, debian

I encountered a strange behavior while working on Docker. I created a simple nuget image as follow `Dockerfile.nuget`

```
FROM debian
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y nuget
```

and created its docker image `docker build -t nuget -f Dockerfile.nuget .`

However, I am unable to `RUN nuget` from this nuget image. I need to run the nuget-cli during the build of an image, instead of running a container instance. For example: a simple `Dockerfile.sample`

```
FROM nuget
RUN nuget
```

When running `docker build -t sample -f Dockerfile.sample .`

```
[+] Building 6.1s (4/5)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.sample                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 59B                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nuget:latest                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/nuget                                                                      0.0s
 => [2/2] RUN nuget                                                                                                6.0s
 => => # [output clipped, log limit 100KiB/s reached]
```

The log output producing lots of blank lines every miliseconds. You can try it out in your machine with `--progress=plain`, and help me understand why this happen, and what can be done about it.

As a starting point, I figure out what might have caused this, and suspect that it has something to do with the TTY output. Because only when I run the docker with a pseudo-tty, the nuget works. i.e.

- This goes crazy: `docker run nuget nuget`, print infinite blank stream
- And this works: `docker run -t nuget nuget`, print the usage guide.